# Server Sent Events in Spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, server-sent-events

I am using Spring boot with thymeleaf template engine. I need to push updates from server to browser if new objects are saved database. But since sse only allows sending text data, how can i pass the objects using sse. Only thing I have read until now is I can convert string to json using JSON.parse() method. But that will not work for me because thymeleaf uses objects to render html. I am new to these terms, so please help me and any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf is a template engine that allows you to render your pages on the server.

A basic example can look like the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SampleViewController {

  @GetMapping
  public String getIndex(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "duke");
    model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
    return "index";
  }

}
```

When a user now requests `/`, the `index` template is rendered with the `Model` we pass to it, and e.g. replaces:

```
<h2>
  <span th:text="'Hello, ' + ${message}"></span>
</h2>
```

after rendering with

```
<h2>
  <span>Hello, duke</span>
</h2>
```

This is more or less *static* as the rendering only happens when someone requests this page.

In your case, you need additional, dynamic behavior. Therefore you can introduce JavaScript to your Thymeleaf template and start using SSE (e.g. by following this [tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)). So you'll basically register to some SSE event stream and update your page on the client-side, whenever an event is sent from the server.

You can add the following to your Thymeleaf templates:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">


</script>
```

and add the missing JavaScript parts to make SSE work.

So using Thymeleaf as a template engine to render server-side pages does not limit you to also add JavaScript to your pages to have dynamic behavior on the client-side (e.g for SSE, WebSockets, AJAX calls).

Answer (score 0):

As rieckpil said you cannot archive your goal directly by serializing JSON and sending it with the SSE-Event.
You got at least following two options

1. If you send JSON with your SSE-Event, use Javascript to handle the replacement of the content.
2. Consume the SSE-Event and trigger a Spring Controller which just renders your desired Thymeleaf fragment.

I went the second route and used [Htmx](https://htmx.org) as a helping library to reduce my involvement with Javascript code.

So my html page contains following code

```
<div hx-ext="sse" sse-connect="/register">
  <div id="score-wrapper" hx-trigger="sse:message" hx-get="/game"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/htmx.org/dist/htmx.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/htmx.org/dist/ext/sse.js}"></script>
```

This calls a Spring Controller with the endpoint `/register` on page load containing

```
private SseEmitter sseEmitter;

@GetMapping("/register")
public SseEmitter registerSseEmitter() {
    sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    sseEmitter.onCompletion(() -> log.info("SseEmitter is completed"));
    sseEmitter.onTimeout(() -> log.info("SseEmitter is timed out"));
    sseEmitter.onError((ex) -> log.info("SseEmitter got error:", ex));

    return sseEmitter;
}
```

and triggers the Spring Controller endpoint `/game` every time a SSE is received.

```
@GetMapping("/game")
public ModelAndView renderGame() {
    Game game = gameEngine.fetchGame();
    GameViewModel viewModel = GameViewModel.create(game);
    return new ModelAndView("fragments/game", "model", viewModel);
}
```